# Combobox not displaying correctly after creating new record in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days so I decided to create a simple stand alone test project to demonstrate my problem.

I'm using visual studio 2008 with C# to create a windows form application.
My Database is SQL Express.  I have a Combo box bound to a table that has only two columns ID and Name.

My test application matches Cleaners to Buildings.
Each Building can have one Cleaner one Cleaner can have many buildings.

Cleaner table has two columns 
CleanerID 
CleanerName

Building Table has three columns
BuildingID
BuildingName
BuildingCleanerID

If I manually populate the tables with data it all works.
However I want to be able to create new buildings if they don't exist then select a cleaner from the existing records.  The problem is when a new record is created the previously displayed cleaner is still in the dropdown not the value from the new record I just created i.e. the first record at Id 0, I named "Select One" .  I have tried cleanerNameComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; in different locations in the code but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I have used the GUI to link up all the properties of the combobox.
Here is the code from the main form.
Let me know if there is a way I can post my test project if anyone wants to test if for themselves.  I'm probably missing something simple here but it is driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance David.

[image: Screen Shot]
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //This line of code loads data into the 'testComboDataSet.Cleaner' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.cleanerTableAdapter.Fill(this.testComboDataSet.Cleaner);

        }

        private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowsFound = this.buildingTableAdapter.FillBuildingByBuildingID(this.testComboDataSet.Building,Convert.ToInt32(buildingIDTextBox.Text));
            if (rowsFound == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Building Not Found, Create new record","Info");
                TestComboDataSet.BuildingRow newbuildingRow;
                newbuildingRow = testComboDataSet.Building.NewBuildingRow();

                try
                {
                    // Set the initial values
                    newbuildingRow.BuildingCleanerID = 0;
                    newbuildingRow.BuildingName = "Not Set";

                    // Add the row to the building table
                    this.testComboDataSet.Building.Rows.Add(newbuildingRow);

                    //  Save the Building table row to the database
                    this.buildingTableAdapter.Update(this.testComboDataSet.Building);

                    cleanerNameComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    //
                    MessageBox.Show("New Building Created", "Info");
                }
                catch (System.Exception er)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to create new building\n" + er, "Error");
                }

            }

        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.buildingBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.testComboDataSet);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** 
Something is updating the details in the cleaners table.
Not sure how this can be.  I Only write to the building able.
Do I have my Data Bindings for the Combo box totally wrong?

The cleaners table started off as

0 select one

1 Cleaner A

2 Cleaner B

3 Cleaner C

4 Cleaner D

5 Cleaner X

In my program I changed Building A from Cleaner A to Cleaner X.
And now the cleaners table looks like this.
[image: Contents of the Cleaners Table]

Answer (score 0):

As I expected the answer was simple.

The real problem was that I had dragged the CleanerName field (as a combobox)from the DataSources Tab onto my form.  I should have dragged the whole cleaner table (as a combobox) from the DataSources tab onto my form.  This just left me to set the "Selected Value" in the properties of the control to BuildingCleanerID from the Building table.

The sad part is it looks identical in the designer, but now it works exactly as you would expect and the code is dead simple.

Additionally to avoid updating the Cleaners table unexpectedly, I needed to change the Combobox drop down style from "DropDown" to "DropDownList"  This blocks the user from typing new stuff into the drop down box.

As usual I hope this helps someone else with the same problem
David